# Encoding hierarchy information in objects

Tags: database, serialization

I am writing code that will assign entities to transaction. Each transaction has a counterparty entity.

### Requirements

- The entities should be (de-)serialisable (from pydantic models into JSON and vice versa)
- Individual entities will be stored in a database
- Entities have some hierarchy, e.g. a Supermarket is a type of Company.
- If possible, I would like to pattern match entities, such that e.g. a `case` statement that expects a Company will accept both a Supermarket and a Company, but another `case` statement expecting a Supermarket will not accept any other Company.

### Design

I have two specific ideas:

#### Idea 1:

```py
class Entity():
    name: str

class Company(Entity):
    pass

class Supermarket(Company):
    pass

Aldi = Supermarket(name="Aldi")  # this will be stored as a database entry.

class Person(Entity):
    pass

...
```

#### Idea 2a

```py
class Entity():
    name: str
    type: EntityType

class EntityType():
    parent: EntityType | None
    children: list[EntityType]


Company = EntityType(parent=None)  # will be hard to backfill the children...
Supermarket = EntityType(parent=Company)

Aldi = Entity(name="Aldi", type=Supermarket)

...
```

#### Idea 2b

```py
class Entity():
    name: str
    type: EntityCode

class EntityCode():
    l0: str | None
    l1: str | None
    l2: str | None
    l3: str | None

Company = EntityCode(
    l0 = "Company"
)

Supermarket = EntityCode(
    l0 = "Company"
    l1 = "Supermarket"
)
Aldi = Entity(name="Aldi", type=Supermarket)

...
```

I am unsure whats best to use. I could make all 3 work with my requirements. Option 1 uses inheritance, which is a bit harder to serialise since all objects have the same properties so hard to know which entity a given json is unless we store the class name aswell. Also its harder to find the specific parent of an entity. Finally, inheritance may be a waste since entities dont really differentiate from each other with special properties etc.

Option 2a and 2b encode the information using a property, while the actual entity instances are of the same type `Entity`. Both are easy to serialise and store in a database. 2a will be hard to backfill the children, and 2b is a bit restrictive for entities that dont have 4 levels of hierarchy. Also ideally i would use a different type instead of str for these levels, maybe some literal value or enums.

Anyway, I am interested if anyone has an opinion on this, or if this is maybe a well-known problem and there is one way or another of solving this that is superior.

Comment: Many Json libraries support polymorphic serialization, usually by storing a identifier for the concrete type as a property. I'm not familiar with the python echo system, but I would expect at least some builtin support for this.

Comment: `Also it's harder to find the specific parent of an entity` Why do you need to persist/serialize the hierarchy? Why would you mix models if, indeed, they are of different complexity?

Comment: @JonasH it probably is possible as well in python, so this is not a limitation. I am more interested if there are other good arguments favouring one method over the other.

Comment: @Laiv I am not sure i 100% understand your comment. I do not need to serialise hierarchies per se. I dont need to store in my DB that supermarket is child of Company, that can indeed be retrieved by my model defined in the code. What is your suggestion though?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it just about polymorphic serialization? If so, why not just let the library do its thing? Or by "hierarchy" do you mean some type of tree or graph of objects, not the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: I understand the question may be a bit vague. I want to encode certain information, and I see two main ideas of doing it. Both of these have advantages and disadvantages, among others in relation to serialisation. I am asking this here to see if anyone has faced a similar problem or if anyone has strong arguments in favor or against using one or the other of the suggested approaches.

Comment: @charelf The problem is in here `I am asking this here to see if anyone has faced a similar problem`. A similar problem doesn't mean _"exactly the same problem, constraints, context, priorities, non-functional and functional requirements and needs then you have"_. We can not extrapolate our solutions to yours. If you already have one, go with it, don't waste your time wondering or distressing. The final solution will come alone as you delve into the problem. Bear also in mind that, asking for opinions is off-topic. They only lead to opinionated answers and debate.

Comment: ok fair point, thanks for the feedback though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2b limits the levels artificially. At the same time, it forces all levels to have all the identifiers without ensuring consistency. And using the identifiers may require complex hard coded rules, which makes maintenance difficult.

Option 2a is more powerful and convenient to use. But you loose the benefit of the entity specialization. i.e supermarkets
no longer have specific behaviors or additional attributes. This option should be chosen if the entity specific behaviors can be encapsulated in a strategy, or if you're in a data-only object model (not recommended).

Option 1 looks elegant and very robist on view of future evolutions.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it answers my question asking for feedback/comments. I have decided to go for option 2b (in a slightly modified version) to follow more closely the existing hierarchies of dutch SBI codes (similar to the european NACE codes)

Comment: Actually my solution is closer to 2a in hindsight...

Comment: @charelf I missed this contextual information. Indeed, you'll not replicate in your code the class hierarchy for all the NACE, which is more a statistical classifier than a behavioral one. In this cas I'd have gone for 2a as well.

Comment: Yes, in hindsight this piece of context would have been useful to include in the question. Thanks for confirming my choice then.